# Errors when attempting to install Vim on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, package-management, software-installation

My computer is running Ubuntu 12.04. I tried to install a few programs (including Vim) through the Ubuntu Software Center, but it showed that there was no internet connection even though I was connected to internet. Then I found out that [vi Editor](https://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-use-vi-editor) will be required to allow me to save my password and proxy in the system configuration.

Apart from that, I also tried to install the programs through the terminal, but the same problem occurred -- it says this is not a candidate for install.

I tried to install Vim using command `sudo apt-get install Vim-nox`, but it responded that the package was broken and showed many failures.

Comment: sounds like you have have a network problem.  However you shouldn't need to use the `vi` editor specifically to edit your config files.  Just use `nano` instead, it should already be installed.

Comment: Can you provide exact error message

Comment: we need exact message what its saying to you and as you said there are broken pkg's you need to run as sudo apt-get install -f in your terminal .

Comment: If you want **vim**, then just type: **sudo apt-get install vim**

Answer (score 1):

you carefully type command first.

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

link:[Installation Vim on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VimHowto)

I hope to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo apt-get -f install` first to fix the inconsistent state of your packages.

If that gives you errors and you still can't install packages, you may need to clear your cache - this can happen if, for example, you connect to one of those wireless networks that asks you to log in via a web page, and ONLY returns that web page for ALL requests until you successfully log in (this will corrupt the local apt cache, if it tries to update while you are connected but not logged in).

ONLY DO THIS IF YOU STILL CANNOT INSTALL PACKAGES AFTER `sudo apt-get -f install`.  It's safe - an apt-get update will replace everything that's in there, whether you were having a problem or not - but, y'know, better not to get in the habit of wildly deleting things unnecessarily. :)

`you@box:~$ sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*`

Reference on the apt list corruption: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+bug/1055614